# React Native Deep Linking - Android application opening for all URLs (For configured domain)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-deep-linking, expo-linking

We converted our native Android application to React native app and used expo managed workflow for new application. For deeplinking we used [linking documentation](https://docs.expo.io/guides/linking/) from expo and everything worked fine. But recently we noticed For some users(Particularly samsung devices), Android App is opening for all URLs (For configured domain).

Intent Filters settings:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "VIEW",
          "data": [
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/jobs"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/can/recommended-jobs"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/can/cv-views"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/can/conversations"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/can/profile/basic-info"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPattern": "/.*/jobs/.*-.*"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/mobile/can/profile"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/mobile/can/cv-views"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/mobile/"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPrefix": "/mobile/jobs/country"
            },
            {
              "scheme": "https",
              "host": "*.domain.com",
              "pathPattern": "/mobile/jobs-in-.*/.*/.*"
            }
          ],
          "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even after expo ejection in Expo bare workeflow above issue still exists.

After ejection Android Menifest looks like this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.android.dev">
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    <meta-data android:name="expo.modules.updates.EXPO_SDK_VERSION" android:value="41.0.0"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.company"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.company.android.dev"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/jobs"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/can/recommended-jobs"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/can/cv-views"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/can/conversations"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/can/profile/basic-info"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPattern="/.*/jobs/.*-.*"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile/can/profile"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile/can/cv-views"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile/"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPrefix="/mobile/jobs/country"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*.domain.com" android:pathPattern="/mobile/jobs-in-.*/.*/.*"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?
I have had this issue for months on all android devices I'd say.
Three months ago it was working fine, all of a sudden it stopped working for all android devices.